# error-how to solve the Undefined control sequence

Tags: equations

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.226 ... 1}} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm
                                                  { }}L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta )\\
```

How to solve issue?
which is from:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
{X_{k + 1}} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm{ }}L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta 
)\\
{\rm{       }} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm{ }}{\left\| X 
\right\|_*} + {\raise0.7ex\hbox{$\beta $} \!\mathord{\left/
{\vphantom {\beta  2}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\!\lower0.7ex\hbox{$2$}}\left\| {X - (Y_k - {\raise0.7ex\hbox{$1$} 
\!\mathord{\left/
{\vphantom {1 \beta }}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\!\lower0.7ex\hbox{$\beta $}}Z_k)} \right\|_F^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: I suspect you have reformatted the error message which makes it very hard to tell which command is undefined. the undefined command is shown by a line break. probably it is `\rm` which has not been defined by default in latex for 25 years.

Comment: what is the intention of this code which is very strange!  `{\rm{       }}` (if you define `\rm`) is the same as `{}` `\lower` and `\raise` are tex primitives that you wouldn't expect to see in a document, and the whole expression is an equality so should be in a display math enviornment not an `array`

Comment: thank you so much sir, I convert the equation from Mathtype, it works in another template, but shows error in a current conference template in overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reformatted the error message which obscures which command is undefined.

Also you did not provide a test file.

If you set your example using `article`  it works without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
{X_{k + 1}} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm{ }}L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta 
)\\
{\rm{       }} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm{ }}{\left\| X 
\right\|_*} + {\raise0.7ex\hbox{$\beta $} \!\mathord{\left/
{\vphantom {\beta  2}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\!\lower0.7ex\hbox{$2$}}\left\| {X - (Y_k - {\raise0.7ex\hbox{$1$} 
\!\mathord{\left/
{\vphantom {1 \beta }}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\!\lower0.7ex\hbox{$\beta $}}Z_k)} \right\|_F^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
```

---

koma script defines `\rm` to give an error:

```
! Class scrartcl Error: undefined old font command `\rm'.

See the scrartcl class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 ... + 1}} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm
                                                  { }}L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta
?
```

---

other classes may not define `\rm` at all in which case you get the primitive undefined command error message but again with a line break highlighting the issue

```
\documentclass{minimal}
```

---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 ... + 1}} = \mathop {\arg \min }\limits_X {\rm
                                                  { }}L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta
?
```

---

Normally use of `\rm` should be replaced by `\mathrm` but here it is applied to nothing so it is simpler just to delete it `\{\rm{ }}` is the same as `{}`.

A more reasonable markup might be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X_{k + 1} &= \mathop {\arg \min }_X L(X,{Y_k},{Z_k},\beta)\\
& = \mathop {\arg \min }_X \| X\|_* + \nicefrac{\beta}{2}
\| X - (Y_k - \nicefrac{1}{\beta}Z_k)\|_F^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```